# How to build a graphical chart in a c# application from a datagridview with evolving data points

Tags: c#, database, graph, charts, datagridview

I have a c# application for a scientific experiment. This application stores the data in a data grid view. Each line item has three recorded parameters v1, v2, v3, and an experiment ID, and a step number. The column names for these five items are v1, v2, v3, Animal ID, Step.

I need to make graphical charts which should generate automatically the moment a new Animal ID enters the Data Grid view. For each chart, the number of series should be 3, denoting v1, v2, v3 of whose values should be shown on the Y axis. The x axis should have an equal number of points with these three series in each as are the number entries of that Animal ID in that Data Gridview, and each point should be names as Step "*Value of Step*".

For example: Under the column [Animal ID], if I have the ID "Tiger1" appearing twice, first in one row with the value under the Step column as "2" & the value under the v1, v2, v3 columns as "1" "2" "3" respectively... and then in another row with the value under the Step column as "27 & the value under the v1, v2, v3 columns as "4" "5" "6"", it should show a graph where Y axis shows the values of v1 v2 and v3 and the x-axis has two points named Step 2 and Step 27 with three series columns each of v1 v2 v3. And the moment another line item enters the DataGridView with the same Animal ID and a different Step number, another point on the X-axis should be generated with the three series of v1v2v3.

Screenshot of DataGridView
[image]

Design of the kind of chart I am trying to build
[image]

I am new to coding and my current incomplete code doesn't seem to be going anywhere. Need help.

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlconf2.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlconf2.Open();

        SqlCommand CHcmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ExpData where SystemUser = '" + textBox15.Text.Trim() + "' and [Animal ID] = '" + comboBox6.Text.Trim() + "' ");
        SqlDataReader myreader;
        try
        {
            myreader = CHcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                SqlCommand stepcmd = new SqlCommand("Select DISTINCT Step as step from ExpData where SystemUser = '" + textBox15.Text.Trim() + "' and [Animal ID] = '" + comboBox6.Text.Trim() + "' ;");
                int step = int.Parse();
                //this.chart1.Series["Measurements"].Points.Add(myreader.GetInt32("v1"), myreader.GetValue("v2"));
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        sqlconf2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It is often helpful to post an image of the type of chart you aim at.  The way to add points to a seies is usually either AddXY or binding the series to a datasource.

Comment: @TaW Hi, I have edited my query to include image examples of what I am trying to do.

Comment: hi, you use wpf for winform ??

Comment: a) your queries are open to sql injection. You need to learn about parametrized queries! b) your code to add points  has issues: it always adds to the same series when you really want to have and use three series. It should use Points.AddXY. Not sure about the use of Distinct. Does the DGV show the values you expect?

Comment: @behroozbcI I am currently using only WInform